# Get actionbar in appcompatpreference

Tags: android, android-actionbar, preferences

I set  `<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`in my style.xml cos I want to use a custom action bar in my main activity. So my appcompatpreference doesn't load the action bar. What could I do to get an action bar in preference.

Here is my SettingsActivity.java

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatPreferenceActivity {

    private static final String TAG = SettingsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        // load settings fragment
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MainPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public static class MainPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_main);


        }
    }
```

Comment: Can't you use a `PreferenceFragment` inside a normal `AppCompatActivity`? You'll likely need to create your own toolbar in a layout file and set it as the support actionbar

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate layout for your Toolbar,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   .....
   .....
   />
```

Now set it in onPostCreate() of the SettingsActivity

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout rootLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.list).getParent().getParent().getParent();
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.toolbar_layout, root, false);
        rootLayout.addView(toolbar , 0);
    }
```

Comment: But this toolbar overlap with the settings